# Como evitar que ConstraintLayout ocupe toda la pantalla

Tags: android, constraint-layout

Tengo creado en el **Activity** principal un menú horizontal, donde a uno de sus ítem he puesto un botón que llama a una **Activity** que contiene un `ConstraintLayout`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando entro en ese Activity ocupa toda la pantalla ocultando el menú.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de los xml

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.SoCu.CirDocu.MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.FondoMenu"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/texto_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="clip_vertical"
                android:text= "@string/titulo_app"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

         <com.SoCu.Docu_AD.custom_views.HorizontalScrollMenuView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:backgroundMenuColor="#0099cc"
            app:backgroundNotifications="@color/colorAccent"
            app:icon_height="30dp"
            app:icon_width="30dp"
            app:item_backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:item_colorSelected="#ffffff"
            app:item_textColor="#ffffff" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ver_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/explist_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/Gris1"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:listSelector="#bfbfbf" >
    </ExpandableListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**apuntes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minHeight="180dp"
tools:context="com.SoCu.CirDocu.Apuntes"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_nombre"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="176dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/txt_nombre"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_contenido"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_contenido"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#1634F7"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_nombre" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:onClick="Guardar"
    android:text="@string/boton_Guardar"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_contenido" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="Consultar"
    android:text="@string/boton_Consultar"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_contenido" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Como puedo dejar ese activity por debajo de los menus para que se puedan ver?

Gracias.

Comment: el FrameLayout está fuera del DrawerLayout, y el menú tiene más opciones que necesitan del FrameLayout si lo quito creo que otras parte dejarían de funcionar, y si, con los dos menús tengo un martirio, no he conseguido que funcionen los dos a la vez, por mas vueltas que he dado cambiando el activity_main.xml de esta forma solo funciona el horizontal que es con el que estoy haciendo pruebas, como te digo si consigo que funcione el menú horizontal, no funciona el vertical, y al revés,

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo para ver como dices, porque lo he intentado y algo no estoy haciendo bien, pero mira que he comentado que tengo puestos dos menus.

Comment: Tengo un lio en el MainActivity.java, el menu vertical, es un poco especial, esta creado sin el codigo que pone Android Studio, si quieres quito todos el codigo con el que estoy probando y te lo pongo, porque no se si sera como el que tienes tu creado.

Comment: Te entiendo, a veces lo mejor es darse un respiro... :)

Answer (score 1):

Este seria el activity_main.xml es un DrawerLayout, contiene el menu lateral izq dentro de un NavigationView, dentro de el pondremos un app_bar_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Este se seria el app_bar_main.xml y dentro de este layout incluimos el apuntes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.EventoActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/horizontal_menu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </HorizontalScrollView>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/apuntes" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

En layout apuntes, el contexto debe ser MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.SoCu.CirDocu.MainActivity">

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Puedes jugar poniendo cosas dentro del AppBarLayout y Toolbar, para que se quede como a ti mas te guste.

En el apuntes.xml puedes cambiar el ConstraintLayout por un NestedScrollView, por si al poner el movil horizontal algo se recorta, eso ya es como tu veas:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.SoCu.CirDocu.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Gracias Santiago mañana lo vuelvo a repasar que el código es muy diferente al código que yo tengo, no se si con el app_bar_main tienes creado el menú vertical para que del item principal muestras el menú horizontal, porque si es asi, supongo que cuando selecciones otro item del menu vertical, el menu horizontal desaparece. No entiendo muy bien los dos últimos códigos del apuntes.xml si lo que se ha creado es un ConstraintLayout como el ultimo código no lo tiene, lo que comentas de darse un respiro ya casi tenia abandonado el código para poner el menú vertical, no he llegado hacerle funcionar.

Comment: El menu vertical lo agregas con el NavigationView. Saludos.

Comment: No puede ser, cuando uno está deseando una cosa parece que todo se pone en contra, y mira que tenía ganas desde hace muchos meses poder solucionar lo de poder trabajar con los dos menús, te escribo desde el móvil, solo para que sepas que por desgracia no he podido probar nada todavía, espero que mañana no tenga el día tan complicado como hoy, luego si puedo borrare este mensaje para que no se extienda mucho.

Comment: Bueno el post anterior no se como se puede eliminar, ya he probado y al final he tenido que dejarlo como lo tenia, no he sido capaz de adaptar el código que yo tengo al que tu has puesto, para que funcionen los dos menus, y para que el apunte.xml no se quede por encima de los menus.